# SqlDataReader returning wrong field value

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I'm having trouble with `SqlDataReader`. I have a function like this

```
public static ObservableCollection<DelayedShipmentDTO> getAllDelayShipmentsInfo()
{
    ObservableCollection<DelayedShipmentDTO> retlist = new ObservableCollection<DelayedShipmentDTO>();

    SqlConnection conn = null;
    SqlCommand command = null;

    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();

        command = new SqlCommand("Select * from Delay", conn);

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DelayedShipmentDTO dto = new DelayedShipmentDTO();
            dto.setPromiseddate((DateTime)reader["PromisedDate"]);
            dto.setNewShipmentdate((DateTime)reader["NewShipmentDate"]);
            dto.setOrdernumber(reader["OrderNumber"].ToString());
            dto.setDelaytype(reader["DelayType"].ToString());
            dto.setDelayreason(reader["DelayReason"].ToString());
            dto.setIsnotified((bool)reader["isnotified"]);
            dto.setNotificationtype(reader["NotificationType"].ToString());

            //DelayedShipmentDTO dto = new DelayedShipmentDTO((DateTime)reader["PromisedDate"], (DateTime)reader["NewShipmentDate"], reader["OrderNumber"].ToString(), reader["NotificationType"].ToString(),
            //    reader["DelayType"].ToString(), reader["DelayReason"].ToString(), (bool)reader["isnotified"]);

            retlist.Add(dto);
        }

        return retlist;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        throw new Exception(ex.Message); 
    }
    finally 
    {   
        if (conn != null) 
        { 
            ((IDisposable)conn).Dispose(); 
        } 
    }
}

public class DelayedShipmentDTO
{
    DateTime promisedDate;
    DateTime newShipmentDate;
    string orderNumber;
    string notificationType;
    string delayType;
    string delayReason;
    bool isNotified;
public DelayedShipmentDTO() { }
    public DelayedShipmentDTO(DateTime p, DateTime n, string o, string sn, string dt, string dr, bool i)
    {
        promisedDate = p;
        newShipmentDate = n;
        orderNumber = o;
        notificationType = sn;
        delayType = dt;
        delayReason = dr;
        isNotified = i;
    }

    public void setPromiseddate(DateTime value) { promisedDate = value; }
    public void setNewShipmentdate(DateTime value) { newShipmentDate = value; }
    public void setOrdernumber(string value) { orderNumber = value; }
    public void setNotificationtype(string value) { notificationType = value; }
    public void setDelaytype(string value){delayType = value;}
    public void setDelayreason(string value) { delayReason = value; }
    public void setIsnotified(bool value) { isNotified = value; }
}
```

My SQL Server table is set up like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Delay]
(
    [DelayID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PromisedDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [NewShipmentDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Ordernumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DelayType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DelayReason] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [isNotified] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [NotificationType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The problem is when I'm reading the each row, all strings default to the `ordernumber` field value. There is no problem with the boolean as well as the date.

EDIT 1: For clarification on the result of method

```
PromisedDate = 1/21/2016  - correct
NewShipmentDate = 1/22/2016 - correct
isNotified = true; - correct
OrderNumber = "123456" -correct
DelayType = "123456" - wrong 
DelayReason = "123456" - wrong 
NotificationType = "123456" - wrong
```

EDIT 2: found the bug!
It was a mistake on my part on the addRecord using parameters. Thank you for those who tried to help.

Comment: I'm not even going to get into what you're doing, but, 1) Please use properties. 2) Look into the C# naming standard. 3) Look into a Micro ORM like Dapper to make the object mapping a lot easier.

Comment: I can only suggest to start the debugger and follow your code. As is presented above there is anything that could explain this behavior

Comment: I would have to play around with this as I'm not sure if this is actually a way of populating fields in the DelayedShipmentDTO class but it would appear that you should be using something like: `dto.setPromiseddate = (DateTime)reader["PromisedDate"];` etc...

Comment: Actually, is this all the code? because you use promisedDate as a field name and then try to use setPromiseddate in your reader to store the information which isn't defined in any of this code. I'm going to have to agree with the first 2 comments on all points made.

Comment: Now that I've looked deeply at your code, I see what you're attempting to do and you are not following your own method that takes in arguments. For one thing, you have the last two arguments reversed and you are not passing the information into the method that takes arguments in the first place.

Comment: If you are wanting to return a List<DelayedShipmentDTO> then why do you need to declare 
`ObservableCollection<DelayedShipmentDTO> retlist ` I think since you should consider changing the code to be the following 
`var retlist = new List<DelayedShipmentDTO>()` then change your method signature to return `public static List<DelayedShipmentDTO> getAllDelayShipmentsInfo()` also read up on how to use and or what `ObservableCollection` is

Comment: @MethodMan I want to return an observableCollection because I have a display that will show each record. In that display, im allowing them to remove records which is tied into a dependecy prop. The type of return object is not the problem but the return value of other string field from sql.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you're attempting to do with the code you displayed:

```
while (reader.Read())
            {
                DelayedShipmentDTO dto = new DelayedShipmentDTO((DateTime)reader["PromisedDate"],
                (DateTime)reader["NewShipmentDate"],
                reader["OrderNumber"].ToString(),
                reader["DelayType"].ToString(),
                reader["DelayReason"].ToString(),
                reader["NotificationType"].ToString(),
                (bool)reader["isnotified"]);

                //DelayedShipmentDTO dto = new DelayedShipmentDTO((DateTime)reader["PromisedDate"], (DateTime)reader["NewShipmentDate"], reader["OrderNumber"].ToString(), reader["NotificationType"].ToString(),
                //    reader["DelayType"].ToString(), reader["DelayReason"].ToString(), (bool)reader["isnotified"]);

                retlist.Add(dto);
            }
```

Notice how I'm passing the values into the method DelayedShipmentDTO during instantiation of the class? Please take the advice of the others when it comes to naming conventions and learning how to debug as this code is going to go out of control quickly for you.

Comment: its basically what i have, notice the commented part? i followed the code using debugs, as well as using your suggested modification. I notice that even string tmp  = reader["DelayReason"].ToString() will make tmp equal to the value of reader["OrderNumber"].ToString()

Comment: OK, I just built your table and ran your code and checked retlist on the 2 rows I added and everything seems to be in place. _Sorry about previous post, I didn't see the bottom segment of code for some reason._